After Ubuntu crashed at the login menu is stated giving me this error : Transport endpoint is not connected
I installed  Ubuntu 22.04.04 on my 2009 MacBook Pro.Every thing was working fine until the system un expectedly crashed and after a reboot started displaying this error. Does enybody know how to fix this?
